# API reconhecimento facial

Tags: api, imagem

Pessoal estou querendo trabalhar em um sistema para meu TCC com reconhecimento facial. Existe alguma API que faça isso para mim? Pode ser qualquer linguagem.

Obrigado.

Comment: Respondi, mas fiquei na dúvida agora: você quer reconhecimento facial - reconhecer o rosto de alguém específico - ou detecção facial - identificar uma face em uma imagem?

Comment: reconhecer de alguem especifico ... Na realidade terei que identificar e depois reconhece-lo ...

Comment: Ok. Vê se minha resposta ajuda. Vlw

Comment: irei testar em breve ....

Answer (score 1):

Usa **OpenCV** (Open Source Computer Vision Library: http://opencv.org): uma biblioteca de licença BSD de código aberto que inclui várias centenas de algoritmos de visão computacional. Escrita em **C/C++** com *bidings* para várias outras liguagens como **Java** e **Python**.

Tem uma página (escrita em inglês) explicando como realizar reconhecimento facial: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html.

Answer (score 0):

Usa o opencv em python.

É fácil usar (depois de se entender os conceitos) e funciona bastante bem.

Exemplo aqui:

https://realpython.com/blog/python/face-recognition-with-python/

Comment: Embora o link possa até responder, respostas apenas com links são desencorajadas no site. Procure contextualizar o conteudo no link na resposta, para que ele sirva de complemento ou referencia apenas.